# PHP Simple String Manipulation

Tags: string, parsing

I have a string with multiple lines.  For this example, my string will be this:

```
Name:Jaxo
Description:A person on Stackoverflow
Question:$this->questionName();
```

How could I get just, say, the 'Description'?  I need everything after the description, ie 'A person on Stackoverflow'.  I've tried a regex like this, but it doesn't work: `/^Description:(.+?)\n/i`

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

-Jaxo

Comment: 'description' not is in start of string,you need remove ^ for your regex works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
if (preg_match('/Description:(.+)/im', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Where `$result` is the Description name.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!!

I shortened it to this, as well:
`echo $result=preg_match('/Description:(.+)/im',$subject,$r)?$r[1]:null;`

Answer (score 0):

If there is a newline character separating each part of the label you could explode.

```
$array = explode("\n",$string); // separate params
$desc = explode(":",$array[1]); // separate description
```

This way you could get any of the parameters.

Comment: Correct, but if there are semicolons in the description then `count($desc) > 2` (just a specification).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a="Name:Jaxo
Description:A person on Stackoverflow
Question:\$this->questionName();"; 

preg_match("/Description:([^\n]+)/i",$a,$m);
print_r($m);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Description:A person on Stackoverflow [1] => A person on Stackoverflow )
```